# An easier way to launch JPCSP

Tags: shortcuts

So im getting aggravated that I need to open a terminal and type

```
seal@seal-Dimension-4700:~$ cd /home/seal/Jpcsp
seal@seal-Dimension-4700:~/Jpcsp$ start-linux-x86.sh
```

im wondering if there is a way to make a quick launch so i can skip all that and just launch it from a shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the directory path to the PATH variable by adding the below line to `.bashrc` file,

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/seal/Jpcsp
```

To open `.bashrc` file,

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Then source the .bashrc file,

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

After that you can run the `start-linux-x86.sh` file directly by simply opening the terminal.

Comment: im confused plz give me more detail

Comment: you can directly run the `start-linux-x86.sh` file without going inside the directory `/home/seal/Jpcsp`.

Comment: ok i did that thank you but now it tells me command cannot be found and i spelled everything corectly

Comment: did you change `start-linux-x86.sh` file into an executable one?

Comment: If no,then go into the `/home/seal/Jpcsp` directory and then run `sudo chmod +x start-linux-x86.sh`.To run start-linux-x86.sh file `bash start-linux-x86.sh`.

Comment: yes i went to propertys and made it allow to launch as program. i did have trouble with java recently could that be an issue?

Comment: did the script made by you or not?

Answer (score 1):

Create a shell script on Desktop.The steps are as follows.

1. Right click anywhere on desktop(or in any file,if you wish) and select **create new document>empty document**.
2. Open the file in **gedit**,and type the following in it.

> `#! /bin/sh
>
>   cd /home/seal/Jpcsp
>
>   start-linux-x86.sh`
>
> Save the file as **jpcsp.sh**
>
> Open a terminal and type `sudo chmod +x ./Desktop/jpcsp.sh`
>
> Now every time you want to execute jpcsp,just run **jpcsp.sh** file on desktop.